# State is always one click late

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem with my code, basically setRevalue is always one click late.

```
const Exchanger = () => {
    const [revalue, setRevalue] = useState('null')
    const [valueOfInput, setValueOfInput] = useState('');
    const [valueOfSelect, setValueOfSelect] = useState('');
    const handleClick = () => {
        switch (valueOfSelect) {
            case 'option_1':
                axios.get('http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/rates/a/chf/?format=json')
                .then((response) => {
                        setRevalue(response.data.rates[0].mid)
                        console.log(revalue);
                })
                break;
```

```
    const handleInputChange = (event) => {
        setValueOfInput(event.target.value);
    }
    const handleSelectChange = (event) => {
        setValueOfSelect(event.target.value);
    }
    return(
        <>
        <Input 
        labelText= 'Amount'
        onChange= { handleInputChange }
        value = { valueOfInput }
        />
        <Select selectValue={ valueOfSelect } onSelectChange={ handleSelectChange } /> 
        <Button onClick={handleClick}>Klik!</Button>
        </>
    )
```

On the first click it returns a null which it was supposed to be before the click.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The `console.log(revalue);` in the `handleClick`, whenever you click, it'll set the state for `setRevalue`, but it'll remember in `schedule`, something of `React`, so at that moment, just think like this, that `new state` you want to display is in the cache or something like that, so it'll get the revalue initial state, which is `null` to display at `console.log`, not the newest one. Then when these codes finish, it'll render the page again due to `setRevalue`, that's why you always have the previous state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey so you have a [clousure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) issue there

> In JavaScript, closures are created every time a function is created, at function creation time.

At the time the `.then()` function is created, `revalue` has the value of the last render, That's why even after updating the state with `setRevalue` (and thus triggering a rerender), you get the "old value" (the one corresponding to the render in which the `.then` function was created).

I don't know exactly your use case, but seems like you can achieve whatever you are trying to achieve by doing:

```js
const revalue = response.data.rates[0].mid
setRevalue(revalue)
console.log(revalue);
```

Comment: That actually works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if you want to access to **revalue** right after setting it you have to use useEffect with **revalue** as a parameter , it would be like this

```
useEffect(()=>{
        console.log(revalue);
    },[revalue])
```

now every time revalue change you will have current result

Comment: I tried to do that, but I cant put useEffect in switch. Thought there might be some other options. Well, thanks!